# Remove Zoom slider in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uislider

Im having trouble accessing the Zoom slider that appears by default in an `UIImagePickerController`. This doesn't seem accessible and I must hide it because it is popping up over my `cameraOverlay` view in my UIImagePickerController. Can someone tell me how I might hide the zoom slider that appears when the user pinchs and "zooms"?

Here is what the slider looks like:

[image]

**PS** this is not my custom camera. This is just an image of the slider that is appearing over my `cameraOverlay`

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this? I'm seeing it too....

Comment: No I did not, I unfortunately ended disabling the zoom entirely I believe.

Comment: Still trying to work this out. @chrisx how did you disable zoom entirely? do you have a code snippet I can look at?

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this problem thanks to iOS 10.0. After spending significant time googling and not coming up with anything that worked - I came up with my own solution:

```
myVC.PresentViewController (_imagePicker, false, ()=>_imagePicker.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[1].RemoveFromSuperview();
```

Essentially once the picker view has been presented - "_imagePicker.View.Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[0].Subviews[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU6Ul.png).RemoveFromSuperview();" will be executed to remove the slider view from the camera.

This is likely to break in a future iOS update - so I don't recommend it for production apps. If you are doing a lot of custom camera stuff - it is advisable you use the AVFoundation framework.

Someone should raise a bug with apple that in iOS 10 "imagePicker.ShowsCameraControls = NO;" doesn't actually remove ALL the camera controls.

If you ever need to work out how to do something similar in the future you can use: the "Debug View Hierarchy" button in Xcode to view the viewHierachy and then click on the component you want to remove/guess by looking at the view names:

[Example hierarchy path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU6Ul.png)

In this case, the view that I wanted to remove was the "CAMViewfinderView". Hope this helps!

Note, my code was written in CSharp (Xamarin.IOS) but the same thing will work in objective-c - just slightly different syntax.

-Rufus

Comment: Yes you can see it in the code block I posted (I just updated the formatting so its more visible).

Answer (score 1):

I guess found the best answer to this issue:
The zoom slider is a UISlider, if your imagePickerController's view property contains a UISlider down its subviews, you can set its alpha to zero. 
This issue happens if you upgrade to iOS10.

```
func subviews(_ view: UIView) -> [UIView] {
    return view.subviews + view.subviews.flatMap { subviews($0) }
}

let myViews = subviews(imagePickerController.view)
for view in myViews {
    if view is UISlider {
        view.alpha = 0.0
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found this will disable the zoom feature.

```
imagePicker.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

The above knocks out user interaction for the camera.

Here is what worked for me finally.

Add the cameraOverlay as a subview to the picker.

```
if let overlay = overlayViewController?.view {
           imagePicker.view.addSubview(overlay)
        }
```